# What's the correct syntax for this Postgres query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, update, sqlite

I have a  query which works well in our PostgreSQL db, but we now need to run our app on a MySQL DB **as well**.

The query takes an array of IDs and positions, and updates each record with given ID with a new value for the respective position.

```
  UPDATE items
    SET position = i_vals.position 
    FROM (VALUES (1,12), (2, 13), (3,11)) AS i_vals(id, position)
    WHERE i_vals.id = items.id;
```

How can I rewrite this query to be MySQL and SQLite3 friendly? As a bonus, I'd like to be able to also run in PostgreSQL with the same query, but appreciate that might not be possible

Answer (score 3):

It can be

```
UPDATE items, ( SELECT 1 id, 12 position UNION ALL 
                SELECT 2   , 13          UNION ALL
                SELECT 3   , 11                    ) i_vals
SET items.position = i_vals.position 
WHERE i_vals.id = items.id;
```

or:

```
UPDATE items
       JOIN   ( SELECT 1 id, 12 position UNION ALL 
                SELECT 2   , 13          UNION ALL
                SELECT 3   , 11                    ) i_vals
       ON  i_vals.id = items.id;
SET items.position = i_vals.position ;
```

Comment: is that mysql only?

Comment: @Jasen yes, ths syntax is MySQL specific only. The syntax for `UPDATE` when there are joins involved, it's quite different between the various DBMS. I'm not sure if SQLite supports this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL standard, there is no way to join two tables in an update statement.

An generic way to rewrite your statement would be:

```
UPDATE items
  SET position = case id
                   when 1 then 12
                   when 2 then 13
                   when 3 then 11
                 end
where id in (1,2,3);
```

This is however less flexible for modifications, but should run on any DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

When there are joins involved, it's very hard to write an `UPDATE` that would work in many DBMS because each one has implemented this differently.

The proposed solution for MySQL wil not work for SQLite (as far as I know).

The syntax in the question that works in Postgres, will not work in either MySQL or SQLite.

I think this version will work in all three:

```
UPDATE items
SET position = 
    ( SELECT i_vals.position
      FROM 
          ( SELECT 1 id, 12 position UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2   , 13          UNION ALL
            SELECT 3   , 11                    
          ) i_vals
      WHERE  i_vals.id = items.id
    )
WHERE items.id IN (1, 2, 3) ;
```

The solution suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name is similar but much simpler. I'd prefer that unless you have thousands of rows to update. In that case, you may want to use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE i_vals
  ( id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    position INT NOT NULL
  ) ;

INSERT INTO i_vals
  (id, position)
VALUES
  (1, 12),
  (2, 13),
  (3, 11) ;

UPDATE items
SET position = 
    ( SELECT i_vals.position
      FROM   i_vals
      WHERE  i_vals.id = items.id
    )
-- WHERE items.id IN (SELECT id FROM ivals) ;
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM ivals
        WHERE i_vals.id = items.id
      ) ;

DROP TABLE i_vals ;
```